# Crash when allocating and reallocating memory

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to split a list of ids by a comma and then concatenate each ID to a string but my code isn't working. I think I need to allocate memory dynamically because I have no way of knowing how much buffer space I will need... The program should be able to concatenate hundreds or even thousands of different ids to "tmp" or maybe just a couple. It's up to the user really. I need to be able to increase the size of tmp as needed but I noticed the program crashes if I put too many ids in id_list. What am I doing wrong?

```
size_t size = 512;
char *tmp = malloc(512);

char download_item[100];
snprintf(download_item, 100, "+download_item_id %s ", pch);

if (tmp = realloc(tmp, size += strlen(download_item)) == NULL)
    return;

strcat(tmp, download_item);
```

Comment: The code you show is almost there, but could you please edit to make it a [mcve].  This will make it more likely someone will copy it into their environment, run it, and tell you what they find :)

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is not doing what you expect:

```
    if (tmp = realloc(tmp, size += strlen(download_item)) == NULL)
```

`==` has higher precedence than `=`, so it's assigning the result of the comparison to `tmp`, not assigning the result of `realloc()`. Add parentheses.

```
    if ((tmp = realloc(tmp, size += strlen(download_item))) == NULL)
```